# Filter out data based off multiple user inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

im working on filtering out data.
I'm having trouble extracting the text values in the `tags` property to compare it to the input array.

How would I build this in javascript?

```js
let user_input =["Bananas", "Kiwi"]

const data= [
{
      id: 18,
      username: "james",
      tags: [ { id: 1, text: "Bananas" }, { id: 2, text: "Mangos" }]
    },
{
      id: 17,
      username: "anita",
      tags: [ { id: 3, text: "Bananas" }, { id:4 , text: "Oranges" }, { id:5 , text: "Strawberries" } ]
    },
{
      id: 16,
      username: "david",
      tags: [ { id: 2, text: "Mangos" }]
    },
{
      id: 15,
      username: "nicole",
      tags: [ { id: 6, text: "Kiwi" }]
    },
]
```

im expecting output to be `[{id: 18 ...}, {id:17 ...}, {id:15 ...}]`

Comment: Ok, so to summarize: You want to filter only the elements where one of the tags contains a value from `user_input` as text?

Comment: so if the user_input contains... say.. "bananas","mangos", id 18 will pull up because it contains both values, but it'll also pull u id 17 because of the "bananas" and id:16 because of "mangos". I don't know if that's what you meant?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) call, calling [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on the `tags` array of each iterated object to test if the `user_input` array [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) any of the text values of each iterated `tags` object.

```js
const data = [{ id: 18, username: "james", tags: [{ id: 1, text: "Bananas" }, { id: 2, text: "Mangos" }] }, { id: 17, username: "anita", tags: [{ id: 3, text: "Bananas" }, { id: 4, text: "Oranges" }, { id: 5, text: "Strawberries" }] }, { id: 16, username: "david", tags: [{ id: 2, text: "Mangos" }] }, { id: 15, username: "nicole", tags: [{ id: 6, text: "Kiwi" }] },];

const user_input = ["Bananas", "Kiwi"];

const result = data.filter(({ tags }) =>
  tags.some(({ text }) => user_input.includes(text)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

If instead you wanted to only return objects that matched all the tags in the `user_input` array, you would instead call [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on `user_input`,  [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the tags array of each iterated object to include only the text values, and then check that the returned array `includes()` each tag.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 18, username: "james", tags: [{ id: 1, text: "Bananas" }, { id: 2, text: "Mangos" }] },
  { id: 17, username: "anita", tags: [{ id: 3, text: "Bananas" }, { id: 4, text: "Oranges" }, { id: 5, text: "Strawberries" }] },
  { id: 16, username: "david", tags: [{ id: 2, text: "Mangos" }] },
  {
    id: 15, username: "nicole",
    tags: [
      { id: 6, text: "Kiwi" },
      { id: 6, text: "Bananas" }]
  }
];

const user_input = ["Bananas", "Kiwi"];

const result = data.filter(({ tags }) =>
  user_input.every(tag =>
    tags
      .map(({ text }) => text)
      .includes(tag)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you! Could i have gotten away with using something like .flatMap() or .flat() for this problem?

Comment: Since you're looking to return entire objects .flatMap() and .flat() don't really offer much utility here. Really the only use they would offer for your data set is if wanted to return an array of all the tag objects in a single array.

Comment: I figured much, i just wasn't sure if it worked for multiple levels at a time, or it flattened out ALL levels into one single array

Comment: It accepts a `depth` parameter specifying how deep to flatten, but since you only have one nested level, even the default of 1 would leave you with a 1D array.